# Sampling with python statsmodels ARIMA package

Tags: time-series, python, sampling, arima, stochastic-processes

Assume I have a model following ARIMA(p,q,d) with statsmodels package of python.
Given a time series given by a numpy array "serie", the code looks like:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA  
model = ARIMA(serie, order=(p,q,d))  
fitted = model.fit(trend='c') 
fc, se, conf_99 = fitted.forecast(horizon, alpha=0.01)
```

The variable fc is the expected stochastic process, given the stochastic process "serie", of the forecasting horizon and conf_99 will give me lower and upper bound for prediction, in terms of the confidence interval.

Now, I would like to generate a sample path, i.e. a sampled stochastic process. Obviously I do not want to do this by hand and I would like to know if there is any simple way using in-package function to achieve this. Or if anyone can let me know a code to do so, it would be extremely amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should switch to using the `SARIMAX` model, which has more features and will be better supported going forwards (the `ARIMA` model will be deprecated in the next release).

The results object from a fitted `SARIMAX` model has a `simulate` method that allows you to simulate from the fitted process. If you want the simulation to start after the end of the training sample, then you should pass `anchor='end'` to the `simulate` method.

Example:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import SARIMAX
model = SARIMAX(serie, order=(p, q, d), trend='c')
fitted = model.fit()

fcast = fitted.get_forecast(horizon)
fc = fcast.predicted_mean
se = fcast.se_mean
conf_99 = fcast.conf_int(alpha=0.01)

fitted.simulate(10, anchor='end')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: How to simulate from a model without a dataset i.e., no data to fit? Suppose I want to simulate data from the SARIMA model (1,1,1) x (1,1,1, 12) (or even an AR(1) model) with starting value as 30. Are there better ways than this code -

`import numpy as np

from statsmodel.tsa.api import SARIMAX

zero_dta = np.zeros(208)

modl = SARIMAX(zero_dta, order = (1,1,1), seasonal_order = (1,1,1, 12), trend='c', initialization = 'diffuse')

sims = modl.simulate([0,0.04, -1/3, 1/6, 0.1**2, 1/4], 208)
`